# Loop through a list of Vector3's and see if it is another vector3 and remove it from the list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have a list of Vector3's and I would like to loop through it and see if it equals another Vector3.
I've tried to do this but it won't work i get an error that says 
*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.*

Here is my code:

```
int n = GameManager.instance.blocks.Count;
                while (n > 1) 
                {
                    if (GameManager.instance.blocks[n] == new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.y), 0))
                    {
                        GameManager.instance.blocks.Remove(new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.y), 0));
                    }
                    n--;
                }
```

But i get the error previously stated, what would I change here?

Thanks

Comment: Valid indices are from 0 to Count - 1 inclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set n to your array size it must be n-1 of your total item size.

```
int n = GameManager.instance.blocks.Count-1;//last index is n-1
while (n >= 0)//0 is the first index 
{
    if (GameManager.instance.blocks[n] == new 
    Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.x), 
      Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.y), 0))
      {
          GameManager.instance.blocks.Remove(new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.y), 0));
      }
      n--;
 }
```

Comment: This would attempt to remove a newly created vector instead of the one at current index

Comment: Thank you for the answer! this worked as it helped remove the item with the position of the gameObject the list instead of the one at index 'n'.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use "while" loops with Unity.

```
Vector3 vectorToRemove = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(this.transform.position.y), 0);

for(int i = GameManager.instance.blocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
{
    if(GameManager.instance.blocks[i] == vectorToRemove) GameManager.instance.blocks.Remove(vectorToRemove);
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you use while loops in Unity? That's just silly.

Comment: To avoid freezing in lag situations. It's just an advice, you are free to use non-silly loops.